# Validating the difference in days between two dates

Tags: validation, go

I have some code that is used for validating a condition based on dates, which is always a bit tricky. Here is the code:

```
package rules

type valueInterval struct {
    min int
    max int
}

func (v valueInterval) containsClosed(x int) bool {
    return x >= v.min && x <= v.max
}

func permanentExpiryLimit(entityToCheck bla.Entity, intervalInDays valueInterval, compare time.Time) (RuleStatus, string) {
    if entityToCheck.PermanentExpiry == nil {
        return RULE_NOT_APPLICABLE, "... TODO ..."
    }

    diff := beginningOfDay(*entityToCheck.PermanentExpiry).Sub(beginningOfDay(compare))
    diffInDays := int(diff.Hours()) / 24

    if diffInDays < 0 {
        return RULE_NOT_APPLICABLE, "... TODO ..."
    }

    if !intervalInDays.containsClosed(diffInDays) {
        return RULE_FAILED, "... TODO ..."
    }

    return RULE_PASSED, "... TODO ..."
}

func beginningOfDay(datetime time.Time) time.Time {
    oneDay := 24 * time.Hour
    return datetime.Truncate(oneDay)
}
```

Client code:

```
   status, msg := permanentExpiry(entity, valueInterval{0, 100}, time.Now())
```

The idea is that this code check if the `PermanentExpiry` is at most 100 days in the future from a given `compare` date.

It can be assumed that both dates are in the same timezone. The dates should be compared only on day basis, that's why the time objects are reset to 00:00:00 time.

Still feels a bit clunky and not sure if it's clear that the comparision is done based on full days only. Any comments appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Client code:
>
> ```
>    status, msg := permanentExpiry(entity, 100, time.Now())
> ```
>
> The idea is that this code check if the PermanentExpiry is at most 100
>   days in the future from a given compare date.
>
> It can be assumed that both dates are in the same timezone. The dates
>   should be compared only on day basis, that's why the time objects are
>   reset to 00:00:00 time.
>
> Still feels a bit clunky and not sure if it's clear that the
>   comparision is done based on full days only.

In Go, encapsulate that sort of logic in useful functions like `isExpired`. For example,

`expire.go`:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

// isExpired returns true if date is not before the expiration date.
// The expiration date is start date plus expire days.
// Start is in the same time zone as date.
func isExpired(date, start time.Time, expire int) bool {
    loc := date.Location()
    y, m, d := start.In(loc).Date()
    x := time.Date(y, m, d+expire, 0, 0, 0, 0, loc)
    return !date.Before(x)
}

func main() {
    now := time.Now()
    starts := []time.Time{
        time.Date(now.Year(), now.Month(), now.Day(), 0, 0, 0, 0, now.Location()),
        now,
        time.Date(now.Year(), now.Month(), now.Day(), 23, 59, 59, 0, now.Location()),
    }
    expire := 10 // 100
    for _, start := range starts {
        for i := expire - 2; i <= expire+1; i++ {
            date := now.AddDate(0, 0, i)
            x := isExpired(date, start, expire)
            fmt.Println(
                x, "\t",
                date.Format("2006-01-02 15:04"),
                start.Format("2006-01-02 15:04"), expire,
            )
        }
        fmt.Println()
    }
}
```

Output:

```
false    2017-07-20 11:07 2017-07-12 00:00 10
false    2017-07-21 11:07 2017-07-12 00:00 10
true     2017-07-22 11:07 2017-07-12 00:00 10
true     2017-07-23 11:07 2017-07-12 00:00 10

false    2017-07-20 11:07 2017-07-12 11:07 10
false    2017-07-21 11:07 2017-07-12 11:07 10
true     2017-07-22 11:07 2017-07-12 11:07 10
true     2017-07-23 11:07 2017-07-12 11:07 10

false    2017-07-20 11:07 2017-07-12 23:59 10
false    2017-07-21 11:07 2017-07-12 23:59 10
true     2017-07-22 11:07 2017-07-12 23:59 10
true     2017-07-23 11:07 2017-07-12 23:59 10
```

Comment: So, just to be clear, this is the rewrite of the `func permanentExpiryLimit`? I'm asking because I can't recognize anything from the code I posted.

Answer (score 0):

You client code is incompatible with the argument type of `valueInterval` (I guess you meant to write `valueInterval{0, 100}` instead of `100`?). But this is strange to have `min` for an expiration time, most probably `valueInterval` should just be renamed to `daysUntilExpiration` and be an `int`.

The code could be more idiomatic. Your variables/functions have long names that aren't really useful. You could replace `beginningOfDay` by `truncateDay`, `permanentExpiryLimit` by `checkExpiry`, `entityToCheck` by `entity`, `datetime` by `t`, etc.

Your function does many things (type conversions everywhere!) so that's confusing. You should probably refactor away a function like:

```
// Returns the number of days between two time values.
func dayRange(before, after t.Time) int {
    …
}
```

and then, check directly whether the result is within your interval (without your `containsClosed` auxiliary function, which just hinders readability).

Now, the bad news: computing the number of days between two times, even assuming that they are in the same timezone, is *hard*. Your `beginningOfDay` function only works if you are in UTC. To truncate to day for any timezone, use the solution in the accepted answer of [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36988681/golang-time-time-round-to-day) instead.

Once you have you correctly-truncated times, getting the difference in days between them is not as easy as you think: if you simply divide by `24 * time.Hour` (like you currently do, in a somewhat weird way), this will fail if the times are not on the same timezones. You say "that's not a problem", but you're probably wrong: most places in the world change timezones twice a year, for daylight saving time. So you have to take this into account… You have two options:

- Getting your hands dirty: using the `time.Zone()` function to compute the offset by hand and use this for a correct "day interval" implementation.
- Using a library that does that for you, for example [this one](https://godoc.org/github.com/fxtlabs/date).